# How to make a parameterized command map in vim editor

Tags: linux, vim

I m trying to make a custom command for block commenting, to avoid writing the whole search and replace sequence each time in vim for commenting lines.

What I m trying to do is make a key combination map to which I can pass line numbers as parameter and those should be passed to the .vimrc file and processed there. Is it possible?

For example, I have this in my .vimrc

```
map :pc :17,21s/^/#<CR>
```

Now whenver I will do :pc in vim, it will add a # infront of lines 17-21 (commenting them in python)

Now 17,18 is hard coded in command here but can I make this command parameterized so that I can pass line numbers specifically like :17,21pc and it will take them in map command?

If it is possible then I would love to make the '#' symbol parameterized too so that I can pass in language specific comment symbol, like // in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mappings can't have parameters, but it's typically a command's job (see `:h :command`).

```
command! -range -nargs=? Comment call CommentThis(<line1>, <line2>, <q-args>)
function! CommentThis(l1, l2, lead)
    let l:lead = a:lead == '' ? '#' : a:lead
    exe printf('%i,%is+^+%s', a:l1, a:l2, l:lead)
endf
```

You can use it like this: select some lines with <kbd>V</kbd> and arrows, then:

```
:'<,'>Comment //
```

Of course you can specify the line numbers by yourself : don't select anything, then type:

```
:17,21Comment //
:12,45Comment              " '#' is the default
```

Note: the above code is far from perfect, it's just an example.

**But there is really better if your goal is to comment some lines**: use [NERD Commenter](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/the-nerd-commenter); it automatically chooses the right comment leader depending of the filetype, it allows several kinds of comment styles, it can comment and uncomment...

Here is an example of its use: select some lines with <kbd>V</kbd> and arrows, then type `<leader>cc`, with `<leader>` as `\` by default.

Comment: A comment plugin is a must. There are quite a few comment plugins [out there](http://vimawesome.com/?q=comment). I personally prefer Tim Pope's [commentary.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary).

Comment: @MohitC : yes, `.vimrc` is a good place for it. For `NERD Commenter`, or `commentary.vim`, you have to install first a plugin manager like [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim), which lets you install quickly as many plugins as you want; for example, after install you just have add this line for Vundle : `Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'`. See the docs at the given links.

Comment: NERD Commentor however doesnt allow me to specify a range in its commands, have to highlight lines first. And commentary plugin's 'commentary' word as a command is too big for me

Comment: With NERD Commenter : to comment for example line 15 to 20 (6 lines), do `15G6\cc`